# Directory Mod Rewrite Condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule in my config file create the link to Download data, using the example: example.com/Repository/File/$FILE

```
RewriteRule ^Repository/File/(.*) index.php?p=Repository&Download=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Im trying to avoid directory transversal using a RewriteCond to avoid using ../ .. etc...

I have already have a php script to test the existence of the path, however when I try to use a directory transversal method I get 404,object not found, even tho I have a custom 404 redirect.

Any suggestions of preventing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you request `http://example.com/directory/../otherdirectory` in your browser, your browser will automatically resolve this to `http://example.com/otherdirectory` and request that. There is no server-sided scripting you can do from preventing that.

Besides that, you should not use mod_rewrite for security measures. When someone requests `index.php?p=Repository&Download=sneaky/../.htaccess`, it is `index.php` that should throw a 404 error, not mod_rewrite. You probably even want to restrict slashes in general, and use a whitelist of characters that may be in a filename, in index.php. Something along the lines of:

```
if( !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]+$/", $_GET['Download'] ) ) {
  require_once( "404.php" );
  exit();
}
```